# Google BigQuery Trying to run a TABLE_RANGE_DATE

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, date-range

i am building a partition based table in a dataset and i am trying to query those partitions using a date range.

Here is an example of the data:

`Dataset:
logs
Tables:
logs_20170501
logs_20170502
logs_20170503`

i am trying first the TABLE_RANGE_DATE

`SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([logs.logs_],
                    TIMESTAMP("2017-05-01"),
                    TIMESTAMP("2017-05-03")) as logs_count`

i am keep getting : "**ERROR:Error evaluating subsidiary query**"

i tried those options as well:
single comma:
`SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([logs.logs_],
                    TIMESTAMP('2017-05-01'),
                    TIMESTAMP('2017-05-03')) as logs_count`
Add Project ID:
`SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([main_sys_logs:logs.logs_],
                    TIMESTAMP('2017-05-01'),
                    TIMESTAMP('2017-05-03')) as logs_count`

And it didn't worked.

So i tried to use TABLE_SUFFIX

`SELECT 
  count(*)
FROM [main_sys_logs:logs.logs_*]
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170501' AND '20170503'`

And i got this error : 

`Invalid table name:'main_sys_logs:logs.logs_*`

i have been switching SQL Dialect between legacy SQL ON/Off and i just got different errors on the table name part.

Is there any tips or help for this matter ?
maybe my table name is build wrong with the "_" at the end and this is causing the problem ? thanks for any help.

Comment: Just curious, but is there any reason why you are not using BigQuery's partitioned tables? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables

Comment: I tested it but still got and error , i will try again and post my query here

Comment: I would strongly suggest using partitioned tables if it's not too late!

Comment: as long as you really have dataset `logs` in project `main_sys_logs`and tables named exactly as you described in question - this version `MUST` work - `SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([main_sys_logs:logs.logs_], TIMESTAMP('2017-05-01'), TIMESTAMP('2017-05-03')) as logs_count` - can you please double check!?

Comment: Note that with standard SQL, you should [filter on _PARTITIONTIME](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#limiting_the_number_of_partitions_queried) instead.

Answer (score 0):

So i tried this Query and it worked :

`SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(logs.logs_,
                    TIMESTAMP("2017-05-01"),
                    TIMESTAMP("2017-05-03")) as logs_count`

it started to work after i run this query , i don't know if this is the reason .. but i just query the **TABLES** data for the dataset

`SELECT *
FROM logs__TABLES__`